# How to prevent Livewire exposing data such as models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Is there any way we can adjust the settings so we can able to hide from the responses? I want to hide the `models` key.

[image]

---

I have removed the `public $user` from the properties, but still, the Livewire exposes the User model even though I am only using `Auth::user()` without initiating as a property.

Before:

```
public function mount()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->officialTimezone = $this->user->timezone ?? 'UTC';
    }
```

After:

```
public function mount()
    {
        $this->officialTimezone = Auth::user()->timezone ?? 'UTC';
    }
```

Comment: No. Livewire is stateless, so you have to pass all the data Livewire deals with back and forth in both the request and response. If you don't want it to show up in the payloads, then you must pass it in via `render()` like a normal controller, but that will make so that you cannot use `wire:model`.

Comment: Relevant reading is [Livewire security](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/security) and [Livewire important notes on properties](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#important-notes)

Answer (score 0):

The response that you have highlighted in the Dev tools is actually the response for the `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` and should **ONLY** be enabled in local development environment so that you do not risk exposing this information to the client side. That response has no relation to what you are seeing from your Livewire component, it's just a tool to assist during development. I suggest that you ensure you have your `APP_ENV` set correctly if this is happening on your production server. Also, you should make sure that the `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` is labelled as a dev dependency only.